# Set website JavaScript options with JavaScript disabled

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, settings, noscript

First I'm sorry if this isn't the place to ask this.

Consider this: There is a website that has settings to be set via a drop-down menu in JavaScript. I use Firefox with NoScript, which has JavaScript disabled (also in `about:config`), which means the drop-down menu is unusable, thus I can't make any changes to the default website settings.

Is it possible to set options (somehow, maybe with the Inspect Element?) without turning on JavaScript?

Bonus whim for the possibility to do that when first loading the site (very optional dream).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to manually set these settings yourself somehow in your own browser, or you want the settings to be set for any user who visits your page with Javascript disabled in their browser?

Comment: @nnnnnn Manually (not my site) and then continue with the site recognizing the new settings. I can see them with the Inspector, I can modify them, but nothing happens (probably because I'm modifying the cached page). No idea how else can be done, _if_ it can be done.